# ASP.NET CORE MVC dependicy inversion error with CRUD

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Today i started on dependicy inversion. Before i started implenting this i had a nice CRUD system but now i got some errors. It says "Cannot implicity convert type int to ContractLayer.UsersDto" On the image you can see my controller in the middle and i think its all fine there. The error is not that clear to me. Maybe i forgot to pass an int with the function? Maybe you guys can help me out with this.

Kind regards,

Sem

[Usercollection,UserController,IUserDal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OccA5.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code as `text`. Amongst other things, screen readers have problems interpreting images. And it is advisable to also copy in the full error message. Some of us may be blessed with psychic powers, but the mere mortals among us simply fall back to guessing, if not enough information is provided.

Comment: On left : public Users Create(UserDto user)  On Right : public int Create(UsersDto user)

Answer (score 0):

Both your errors are simply due to type mismatches - not dependency inversion.

The signatures of the errors are

```
public int DeleteUser(int id);
public int CreateUser(UserDto dto);
```

In both cases they return an `int`, but you try to build an `UsersDto`:

```
UsersDto = FactoryLayer.UserDalFactory.GetUserDal().DeleteUser(Id);
```

You either have to change to signature of the corresponding methods in your `UserCollection` or your `IUsersDal` to the correct type.

I'd suggest you change the Delete method to `public void DeleteUser(int id);` and the consuming method to:

```
public void Delete(int id) { ... }
```

When it comes to the create method I would change the signature in your `IUserDal` to `public UsersDto Create(UsersDto dto);` and then also adapt the concreate class that is implementing that interface accordingly.